# I am geting a recurring error as "permission denied" on opening psql in Postgresql.Why am i getting this error?How to solve it?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am new to Postgresql,i installed pgdAdmin4 and all, but now on opening psql i am getting the following errors:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
find: /c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18: Permission denied
find: /c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-1126570350-378795617-2859373091-1000: Permission denied
find: /c/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-1126570350-378795617-2859373091-500: Permission denied
find: /c/Config.Msi: Permission denied
find: /c/hiberfil.sys: Permission denied
find: /c/MSOCache: Permission denied
find: /c/pagefile.sys: Permission denied
find: /c/PerfLogs: Permission denied
```

Comment: Your `psql` command seems to be some kind of batch file, rather than `psql.exe` itself. Try to run `psql.exe` instead (`where psql` will tell you what exactly will be started)

Comment: I did open psql.exe but it is asking for a password.Tried to type in the password used during installation but doesnt work.

Comment: It uses your Windows user, you need to specify the default postgres user (unless you did create a new one), e.g. `psql -U postgres`

Comment: This is the psql shell that comes with the Windows install of Postgres from EDB,. It is using the postgres user, NOTE:```Username [postgres]:```

Comment: I'm not seeing the password prompt in your example. It should be right after the ```Username```. Is there other missing information before you get to the ```find``` errors?

Answer (score 1):

Run the shell as administrator. I had the same problem. Worked for me.